# How to get the latest dates of multiple dates?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have an array of dates some of them contain time like:

```
$dates = array('2016-07-02', '23 júní 2018 13:09', '2017-09-01 08:43', '2018-03-02', '2018-06-26');
```

I have about 90 dates and would like to get the latest 70 for example.

I know how to compare between 2 dates like:

```
$date1=date_create("2017-07-02");
$date2=date_create("2016-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

And:

```
$date = '2018-03-21';
time() - strtotime($date);
```

Is there is a built in function or something that could help comparing all these dates in short time?

Comment: Can you not get the dates in a consistent format and locale?

Comment: Use `array_map('strtotime', $dates)` to get them all converted to timestamps, then sort that.

Comment: @Barmar - that won't work with foreign (internationalised) dates